# Chemmacros Orbital Broken

Tags: chemfig, chemmacros

Currently using the latest versions of all TeX packages. However, the orbital module of chemmacros is broken, as shown in the screenshot. Why is this happening?[image]

This bug can be reproduced using the following code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage[margin=2cm,headsep=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\chemsetup{modules=all}
\chemsetup[orbital]{overlay}

\begin{document}

\orbital[color=red!50]{p}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. Can, please, you add your complete TeX code  to understand your problem?

Comment: There are many chemical package. I think that you should to delete some packages and to put the principal packages.

Comment: Your MWE compiles as it should for me ([resulting orbital image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4KuJ.png)). For the record, I used TeX Live 2021 on Windows 10 20H2, `chemmacros` 2020/11/21 v5.11a, `geometry` 2020/01/02 v5.9, `graphicx` 2020-08-21 and `tikz` 3.1.8b. By the way, why `chemfig` tag? You don't use the package at all in your MWE.

Comment: This could be a problem of nested tikz pictures (orbital within a chemfig figure)